# Why error "error: open /dev/null.lock: permission denied"?

Tags: permissions, kubernetes

I try to config kubernetes, but once I run the command

```
kubectl config set-credentials...
```

I get the error

```
error: open /dev/null.lock: permission denied
```

Why is that? When I search for the error, I only find results for /dev/null, without the ".lock".

There is not even a null.lock file in that location, only the null-file:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       60 Sep  5 08:35 net
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1,   3 Sep  5 09:41 null
crw------- 1 root root  10, 144 Sep  5 08:35 nvram
```

Comment: It _sounds like_ some program tries to use a given pathname to create a lock file, no matter what that pathname is. Something else is providing it the pathname `/dev/null`, probably to say "there is nothing for you to read" or "whatever you write should be discarded", or both. Since I don't know what provides `/dev/null` as the pathname to what other program, I can't unfortunately be more specific about it.